# How to use the Orbit in Foundation 6?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am currently using Foundation **6.3.0** and I don't know how to implement the Orbit in Foundation, because there was no file to be downloaded given on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link this will help https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html